# How do I format the "Diff" output in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, diff, cucumber

I have a scenario outline that compares the results of a method to the array that should be returned.  So I get a series of statements like this when they don't match:

```
expected: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
     got: ["c", "d", "e", "f", "g"] (using ==)
Diff:
@@ -1,2 +1,8 @@
-["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
+["c",
+ "d",
+ "e",
+ "f",
+ "g"]
```

This is not the most succinct or helpful output.  It would be much more helpful to be dipslay like:

```
expected: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
     got: ["c", "d", "e", "f", "g"] (using ==)
Diff:
@@ -1,2 +1,8 @@
-["a", "b"]
+["g"]
```

This way I could instantly see what values were additional or missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Array difference method:

```
(expected_array - actual_array).should == []
```

Comment: This logic is a bit flawed, if the actual has more elements but still contains the expected, this will pass.

 ([1,2,3] - [1,2,3,4]) == [] #=> true

It may be what you are looking for but this will give you false positives if not.